# Unable to reduce size of .vhd in Hyper-V 2008 R2

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a VM that was a P2V using disk2vhd. It is WinXP Pro. It used to reside on a ~200Gb physical disk, so when it was converted, it took that size with it to its .vhd. The disk was only about 70GB used. I wanted to reclaim about 100GB of that disk on the host (current .vhd is 200GB), whereas with Win7 and higher, that's no issue.

I used gparted to reduce the partition to 80GB, booted the OS, made sure it looked good, and that the OS was operating on the reduced partition. I then shut down the VM and attempted to compact the ~200GB .vhd file, and when it finally completed, I was left with a 195GB physical file still.

Anyone know what I can do, or am I stuck with this wasted space?